# Issue with Qt button, I can't find it in UI

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "DatacommAss1.h"

DatacommAss1::DatacommAss1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(handleButton()));
}

void DatacommAss1::handleButton()
{
    // change the text
    ui->pushButton->setText("Ding Dong");
}
```

See my code above, I have a button in my ui file called pushButton, but I cannot access it.

I get and error on 'ui' that says "expression must have pointer type".

I'm new to Qt and have no idea how to fix this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Displays the contents of your .ui file

Comment: try adding: `#include <QPushButton>`

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried adding QPushButton, but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: With the information you show it is impossible to help, first it shows the contents of the file ui, I think this project is small so you can easily upload it to drive, dropbox, github or similar and share the link to see what the problem is.

Comment: Please improve your question, please read the following: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @eyllanesc https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75324053c64c4f82caba6232545170de that's my UI file, you can find the button in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rebuilding your solution, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator sometimes "forget" to rerun qmake. Save all your files (especially .ui) and do Build -> Run QMake (or CMake depending on what you use).

That will regenerate cpp files for your UI. Try rebuilding the project after that.